# Как сделать так , чтобы создатель привата мог настраивать права доступа привата?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

При заходе в войс - создается приват . Я хочу чтобы создатель привата мог настраивать права доступа

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    ctegory = get(member.guild.categories, id = 724263598997635092)
    try:
        if after.channel.id == 745773242626867281:
            prava = {
                member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(manage_channels=True, move_members=True, mute_members=True)
            }
            chan = await member.guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'Приват {member.name}',overwrites=prava, category=ctegory, reason=None)
            await member.move_to(chan, reason=None)
    except:
        pass
    if before.channel == None:
        return
    if before.channel.category_id == 724263598997635092:
        if before.channel.id != 745773242626867281 and len(before.channel.members) == 0:
            await before.channel.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

manage_channels = True, manage_roles = True

Comment: Куда это надо добавить? И отформатируйте код

Comment: Куда, куда, в строчку, где бот права на канал выдает, member: discord.Per,issionOverwrite, вот туда